# Cant see result of html file in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I'm sending (posting) details to server (NodeJs server).
The server send back a html file, which I want to display on iframe.

for some reason I cant see anything.

The server side looks:

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {

    // some logic...
    res.sendFile('userPage.html', {root: __dirname })
}
```

The client side looks:

```
$.post( "/login", 
       { u1: uF1, u2: uF2 }, 
       function(data, status)
       {                                        
            //$("#loginResult").attr('src',data); 
            $("#loginResult").html(data);
            //$("#loginResult").load(data);                              
       });
```

and:

```
<div>           
    <iframe id="loginResult" src="userPage.html" width="100%" height="300" />
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you checked if the variable data is empty or not ?
Please add a console.log(data); to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding like this

```
$("#loginResult").ready(function() {
    $("#loginResult").contents().find("body").append(data);
});
```